# fit background according to screensize in libgdx for obth orientation

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I am creating livewallpaper using libgdx extension. I am adding background for image size of 1024*1024. It is working properly in all device but in tablets when orientation of home screen changes,It is not showing properly. I found many solutions while surfing to resize it on onResize method. I have tried all but none of it working for me.

If anybody have faced and solved this issue of live wallpaper with background using libgdx,Please guide me what i should implement to achieve it. I have pasted code below which I have implemented now:

```
Oncreate method:
textureBG = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/background_1.jpg"));
        sprite = new Sprite(textureBG);
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.viewportHeight = 1024;
        camera.viewportWidth = 1024;

        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth * .5f,
                camera.viewportHeight * .5f, 0f);
        camera.update();
        fpsLog = new FPSLogger();
        stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera));
```

render method with texturebg:

```
batch.begin();
        sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        sprite.draw(batch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're setting your camera to the shape of a square, always 1024x1024. When this is used with the sprite batch, it will distort the square to fit the screen. So I'm guessing you developed it this way and ended up deforming your sprites the opposite way to compensate for the distortion.

What you need to do in resize:

```
void resize(int width, int height){
    camera.viewportWidth = width;
    camera.viewportHeight = height;
    //you can move it to whatever position you want here
    camera.update();
}
```

Then in your other code, scale and move your sprites accordingly. They should not be distorted.

**Edit:**
Based on your comment that you want to the background to always fill the screen:

You can use a FillViewport to get the effect you want.

In `create`, after instantiating your camera, you can instantiate a viewport to fit a 1024x1024 square to cover the whole screen by cropping off whatever is extra:

```
viewport = new FillViewport(1024, 1024, camera);
```

Then you need to resize it in the resize method:

```
@Override
void resize(int width, int height){
    camera.position.set(512, 512, 0); //seems to be where you want it.
    viewport.update(width, height, false); 
}
```

The viewport takes care of updating the camera for you. You only need to update the camera manually if you change its position in `render`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I have tried this ,but it is not working.My background image is only covering half part of screen. I want my background image to cover whole screen in any device and in any orientation. For smartphone which not have orientation change in home screen,it is working. But in tablets,It is not working when orientation changed from landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape.

Comment: Thanks again for your update.By using this,my viewport is being only size of 1024*1024,which looks very small in tablet and having black bars

Comment: Are you sure you're using FillViewport, not FitViewport? FillViewport will not have black bars.

Comment: Yes. I am using FillViewport ,It is working fine in portrait but in landscape it has issue,

Comment: Are you modifying the camera from the render method? It's hard to say what's going wrong without knowing everything in your render method and how you loaded your textures and scale your sprites, etc.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question, I am setting just size of Sprite and drawing it.

Comment: What I mean is, I can only take wild guesses at what is going wrong when I have no idea how big your source textures are, what kind of scene you are creating, what it's supposed to look like and what it looks like now, etc. And you say "size" of Sprite, but Sprite doesn't have a `size` parameter, so that's ambiguous.